# Symfony4: UniqueEntity constraint does not work on GUID field (related entity)

Tags: symfony, unique, uuid, guid, unique-constraint

**upd: Please pay attention: uniqie validation worked perectly UNTIL I changed related PK `User::$id` type from *integer* to *guid*.**

I have an entity `UserWatchlist`, which relates to `User` (many-to-one).
It has complex unique constraint on 2 fields `user` and `direction` :

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserWatchlistRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"user", "direction"},
 *     errorPath="direction",
 *     message="User already has this direction"
 * )
 */
 class UserWatchlist
 {
```

While `User::$id` PK was integer

```
Class User

  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  private $id;
```

uniqueness check worked fine.

But since I updated it to guid type:

```
Class User

  /**
   * @ORM\Id()
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
   * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
   */
  private $id;
```

this check is being ignored and just goes to database-level index checking (if any).

All indexes and foreign keys are OK.

Is this a bug or I did something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: are you talking about your `@ORM\UniqueConstraint`? Because according to docs: "Annotation is used inside the @Table annotation on the entity-class level. It allows to hint the SchemaTool to generate a database unique constraint on the specified table columns. It only has meaning in the SchemaTool schema generation context." (so, it does not affect anything during insert/update/delete on the doctrine side) source https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint

Comment: @Jakumi, no I'm talking about Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity
which has annotation @UniqueEntity() on the class: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html

Comment: @Alexander why don't you run a debugger and check which part is failing? Just put a breakpoint inside the `UniqueEntityValidator`

Comment: @emix nothing fails, it just doesn't go through - just ignoring

Comment: @Alexander in that case: the `UniqueEntity` constraint is only checked when an actual validator tries to validate the entity, which is done by default when the entity is the data object of a form and `$form->isValid()` is called, but you also can retrieve a `ValidatorInterface` via dependency injection and call `validate($entity)` on it (and obviously check the results).

Comment: @Jakumi Of course, it does: `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { ... ` in controller.
Everything in this flow worked PERFECTLY until I changed User::$id type integer->guid

Comment: "working perfectly" can mean so many things, for example "coincidentally flawless". just wanted to be certain ;o) To be honest (and I won't tell you something new here) this behaviour of the UniqueEntity is baffling and not particularly logical. If you're willing to debug, you could modify the UniqueEntityValidator (vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Validator/Constraints/..) and check which values end up in the `$criteria` array around line 101

Comment: Maybe you should have better left the line with `@ORM\UniqueConstraint`. It made it clearer that both database level checks and application level checks are implemented.